# Building riak: "Uncaught error in rebar_core"

Tags: erlang, riak, rebar

I'm trying to build riak. I use Ubuntu 14.04 64 and erlang R15B01. I had to built erlang from sources.

erl --version prints:
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:0] [kernel-poll:false]

I downloaded riak 1.3.0 and when I type make all I receive:

```
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
./rebar get-deps
Uncaught error in rebar_core: {'EXIT',
                           {undef,
                            [{crypto,start,[],[]},
                             {rebar,run_aux,1,[]},
                             {rebar,main,1,[]},
                             {escript,run,2,
                              [{file,"escript.erl"},{line,727}]},
                             {escript,start,1,
                              [{file,"escript.erl"},{line,277}]},
                             {init,start_it,1,[]},
                             {init,start_em,1,[]}]}}
make: *** [deps] Error 1
```

I have no experience with Erlang. I suppose there's something wrong with it but I don't know how to check it. Could you give me any clues how to deal with this problem? I set 777 mode to all the files in /usr/local/lib/erlang where Erlang is installed. I have the same problem with riak 1.4.0

Comment: rebar was not able to start crypto. crypto is erlang app that is used for instance for ssl connections.  Have you built erlang with ssl support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Odobenus Rosmarus is right. I had no openssl dev installed. Even though it's enabled (in erlang configuration script) by default I could install erlang without ssl support. Once I installed openssl dev package, reconfigured and made and installed erlang, everything works great now.